# How to remove a path from $PATH variable in fish?

Tags: shell, path, environment-variables, fish

I am using fish as my shell in Debian and recently (after some upgrade) whenever I try to use command completion I have:

```
set: No such file or directory
set: Could not add component /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm to PATH.
set: No such file or directory
```

Running this:

```
echo $PATH
```

Gives me this:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/local/games /usr/games
```

In my system there is no `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm`, so I understand why fish is complaining, but I cannot find how to remove this path from my `$PATH` variable.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: `grep -R /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm ~/.config/fish /usr/share/fish` ??

Comment: $grep -R /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm ~/.config/fish /usr/share/fish  
/home/superuser/.config/fish/fish_history:grep -R /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm ~/.config/fish /usr/share/fish

Answer (score 63):

The 'fish' way of setting the $PATH variable is to actually use `set --universal fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths /new/path/here`. Then $fish_user_paths is actually prepended to the $PATH variable when a new session starts. The $PATH [documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path) doesn't currently tell you how to delete it though.

In fish every variable is actually a list (array), and you can conveniently access each item directly by using an index/indice. `echo $fish_user_paths` will print out a space delimited version of every item in the list, make the spaces newline with the translate function `echo $fish_user_paths | tr " " "\n"` and then put line numbers on it with the number lines function, `echo $fish_user_paths | tr " " "\n" | nl`. Then delete it with `set --erase --universal fish_user_paths[5]`. You must use `--universal` or it will not work in any new sessions.

If someone has the time, please submit a PR to the [repo](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/doc_src/tutorial.hdr#L530) with this example. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3161).

tldr;

1. `echo $fish_user_paths | tr " " "\n" | nl` // get the number of the one you want to delete, e.g. the 5th one
2. `set --erase --universal fish_user_paths[5]` // erase the 5th path universally so it persists in new sessions

Comment: Why is this so arcane? Shouldn't this be a build in feature and added to the documentation so that people doesn't have to Google and end up here? Oh well..

Comment: I think if we take @clozach's answer here https://superuser.com/a/1212305/30982, which is the addpaths() and removepath() function, and open a PR then that would be the first step to getting it added. Most of the maintainers are pretty good to work with, one seems grumpy to me, but overall I think we would have a good chance. So that is our next step.

Comment: `echo $fish_user_paths` doesn't return anything, but `echo $PATH` returns some stuff.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` return? It should return `/usr/bin/fish` or something like that. My suspicion is that it is a different shell. If it is fish, then what is `fish --version`?

Comment: This `set --erase --universal fish_user_paths[4]` doesn't work for me in v3.3.1 for some reson. No errors, but the path is not being deleted from the list.

Comment: Using spaces as delimiters will break if a path has a space in it. The only 100% safe delimiter is `\0`.

Answer (score 24):

As Elijah says, best practice is to modify the `fish_user_paths` rather than the global `PATH`. To avoid ever having to Google this again…

1. Create a couple of functions that [only modify `fish_user_paths`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#path)
2. Make both functions [autoloading](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#autoloading-functions)

**To add to user paths:**

```
function addpaths
    contains -- $argv $fish_user_paths
       or set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths $argv
    echo "Updated PATH: $PATH"
end
```

**To remove a user path** *if it exists* (partial credit to [this](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/cookbook.fish#how-do-i-remove-a-path-from-the-path-in-fish)):

```
function removepath
    if set -l index (contains -i $argv[1] $PATH)
        set --erase --universal fish_user_paths[$index]
        echo "Updated PATH: $PATH"
    else
        echo "$argv[1] not found in PATH: $PATH"
    end
end
```

**And of course, to make them [autoloading](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#autoloading-functions):**

```
funcsave addpaths; funcsave removepath
```

**Example Usage:**

```
> addpaths /etc /usr/libexec
Modifying PATH: /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
Updated PATH: /etc /usr/libexec /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin

> removepath /usr/libexec
Modifying PATH: /etc /usr/libexec /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
Updated PATH: /etc /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

Comment: Note: I've just discovered that this approach won't remove a path added through some other mechanism; Some dot-file cleanup may be in order if you find a path coming back each time you open a new terminal session.

Comment: This is great, just added to my local!

Comment: This is not working for me. It just prints the back to me, thats all.

Comment: A better solution, added in a more recent version of fish, is to use the fish_add_path command.  https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html

Comment: The removepath function is only working partially because there is a difference between $fish_user_paths and $PATH. I think only variables added with fish_add_path go to $fish_user_paths. Therefore the "set --erase ..." line only works with vars added via fish_add_path. If you replace the "set --erase ..." line with "set -e PATH[$index]" it should work but then it won't delete PATH-vars added via fish_add_path. Doh!

Answer (score 7):

This should erase paths 6 through the last path:

```
set -e PATH[6..-1]
```

The -e flag is erase. See `help set`.

Comment: this will only work for the current session

Answer (score 3):

I have made a fish function following @Elijah Lynn's answer that shows the added fish user added path entries and asks which ones you wish to remove and does so.

It's my very first fish shell script so it's probably not very good but it gets the job done.
Here is the code:

```
function fish_remove_path --description "Shows user added PATH entries and removes the selected one"
    echo "User added PATH entries"
    set -l PATH_ENTRIES
    echo $fish_user_paths | tr " " "\n" | nl
    echo "Select the number of entry to be removed, if more than one separate the values by spaces"
    read -d " " -a PATH_ENTRIES
    for entry in $PATH_ENTRIES
        if string match -qr '^[0-9]+$' $entry
            # "$entry it is a number!"
            set -l FISH_ENTRIES (count $fish_user_paths)
            if test $entry -gt $FISH_ENTRIES
                echo "Index out of bounds, must be between 1 and $FISH_ENTRIES" 1>&2
            else
                echo "Erasing $fish_user_paths[$entry]"
                echo "Press y to continue"
                set -l confirmation
                read confirmation
                if test "$confirmation" = y
                    set --erase --universal fish_user_paths[$entry]
                else
                    echo "skipping..."
                end
            end
        else
            echo "Provided argument $entry is not a number" 1>&2
        end
    end
end
```

In order to use it just create a file called *fish_remove_path.fish* inside *~/.config/fish/functions/*. Then to use it just type `fish_remove_path`.

Here is an example

```
❯ fish_add_path /home/


❯ fish_remove_path
User added PATH entries
     1  /home
     2  /opt/homebrew/bin
     3  /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/
Select the number of entry to be removed, if more than one separate the values by spaces
read> 1
Erasing /home
Press y to continue
read> y

❯ echo $fish_user_paths
/opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/
```

You can give it more than one entry, let's say you want to erase entries 4, 5 and 6. You just have to input them separated by space:

```
❯ fish_remove_path
User added PATH entries
     1  /home
     2  /opt/homebrew/bin
     3  /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/
     4  /whatever1/
     5  /whatever2/
     6  /whatever3/
Select the number of entry to be removed, if more than one separate the values by spaces
read> 1 4 5 6
Erasing /home
Press y to continue
read> y
Erasing /whatever1/
Press y to continue
read> y
.....
```

I hope someone finds this useful, if anyone knows how to do this in a better way then please let me know.

Comment: this is awesome, thank you!

Comment: Use `sed 's/ \//\n\//g'` instead of `tr` to handle spaces in paths.

Answer (score 2):

Reset *fish_user_paths* withtout the path you don't want anymore:

```
 $ set -U fish_user_paths /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/local/games /usr/game
```

More info: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but dusted off by a separate new answer recently.  The question, and existing answers, sound to me a bit like:

*Every time I get out of bed, I cut my foot on the broken glass on floor next to the bed.  What should I do?*

1. Put a bandage on your foot every time you cut your foot after getting out of bed?
2. Or clean up the broken glass?

I hate to be so pedantic, but it seems to me that all of the existing answers (over many years) here have essentially recommended the "bandage" option.

Instead, shouldn't we focus on fixing the root issue?!

> In my system there is no `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfm`, so I understand why fish is complaining, but I cannot find how to remove this path from my `$PATH` variable.

In the case of this question, *why* is this directory being erroneously added in the first place?  Where is it being added?  The best way (it seems to me) to remove a directory from the `$PATH` variable is to prevent it from being added in the first place (clean up the broken glass) rather than attempting to fix it after-the-fact.

Finding where it was added can take a little debugging, but it shouldn't be too difficult.  There are several places to look that I can think of:

##### System configuration

> after some upgrade

The path being referenced is part of the PCMan File Manager, but I couldn't find any issues regarding its library directory being added to the path.

However, if it was a system upgrade that changed this, then start by looking at the system path:

```
sudo -e /etc/environment
```

If that's not it, then next check to see if the directory shows in the `PATH` when running as root:

```
sudo -s
# Fish should be the $SHELL which was executed, but if not ...
fish
set --show PATH
```

If the bad directory is still present, then it is likely a system configuration issue.  If not, then it's likely in the user configuration.

For system, of course, see if you can find a reference to the bad path somewhere in `/etc`:

```
sudo grep -r libfm /etc
```

There's not much other than `/etc/environment` that should impact Fish, but it's worth a check.

There *shouldn't*, as far as I know, be any Systemd units that impact this.  Systemd doesn't (at the time of this answer) have the ability to set the user environment without some fairly extreme gymnastics (i.e. JSON user records, which just aren't used much yet).  That said, at some point it may be worth checking a `sudo grep -rs libfm /usr/lib/systemd` (the `-s` suppresses messages on binary files matching).

##### User-level shell configuration

If it is user-level configuration, then check your user config, of course.  I'd start with:

```
grep -r libfm ~/.config ~/.local
```

If needed, expand the search:

```
grep -r libfm ~
```

You could also substitute `grep -r PATH ~` in there to look for any line changing the `PATH`.  It's possible that the `libfm` directory could be part of another variable that is being used to change the `PATH`.

##### Universal variable

Speaking of, there's always the *chance* that it is being added via `$fish_user_paths`.  However, there's a comment from the OP in one of the deleted answers here that indicates that was *not* the case here.

But for other readers, if it *is* the case, some of the above answers might be right!  To check this, however, simply:

```
set --show fish_user_paths
```

If the bad directory is actually in there, then yes, simply remove it based on the index (best example in [@ElijahLynn's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1091983/1210833)).  For instance, if `$fish_user_paths[3]` is the erroneous path, then:

```
set --erase --universal fish_user_paths[3]
```

In the even smaller chance that it is some other variable being set and used in a `PATH` modification:

```
set --show | grep libfm
```

##### Parent process environment

Finally, there's the chance that the parent process of your shell is modifying the environment before starting Fish.  This would be rare for this type of issue, but it can certainly happen.  `pstree` and look for any common parent process of your shell.  Typically, this will be `login`, `init` (WSL systems), `systemd` itself, or something (not sure what it would be on macOS).

Use `ps -o ppid -p $fish_pid` to get the parent process of your shell, then:

```
sudo -s
cat /proc/<pid>/environ
```

Is the erroneous path there?  If so, then you'll need to determine why it is being set in *that* process (or one of its parents) to remove it.